# read txt file in 2D array solution

Tags: c

i write this code to read a txt file into a 2D array and it's work fine ,but in my input txt i have a 8*8 matrix in the output thay show to me that i have a 37 cols

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, i, j, row, col, nl, cr;

    row = col = nl = cr = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen("image.txt", "r");

    // Figure out how many rows and columns the text file has
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
            nl++;
        if (c == '\r')
            cr++;

        col++;

        if (c == '\n')
            row++;

        putchar(c);
    }

    col = (col - (nl + cr));
    col = (int) (col/row);

    printf("\nnumber of rows is %d\n", row);
    printf("number of columns is %d\n\n", col);



    return 0;
}
```

my input normally :

```
255  50  9  50  1  50  50  1
50  255  50  50  50  50  50 50
50  50  255  50  50  50 50  50
8  50  50  255  50 50  50  50
50  50  50  50 255 50  50  50
50  50  50 50  50  255  50  50
1  50 50  50  50  50  255  50
2 50  50  50  50  50  50  255
```

and the output image is :[image]
someone can help please?

Answer (score 0):

That's funny, I get -

```
number of rows is 8
number of columns is 29
```

The problem is that thanks to using getc, you count the number of actual characters in the text file, when you read 255 for e.g., that's not really a single char with that value, it's 3 chars with the values 50 ('2'), 53 ('5') and 53 ('5'). You'll also count spaces here (which is probably why I got a different results than you did)

You should read them as integers (fscanf for e.g.), or parse them as such according to the acceptable delimiters (space and newlines in this case, I presume), and only then advance your counters accordingly. Alternatively, you can compact your files to a binary format and forget about all the hassle with spaces and newline, one byte per character. They won't be as readable though.

Also note that your code assumes a fixed column count per line, better be sure it's always the case